Realm Kotlin SDK: Cannot modify managed List outside of a write transaction
I do not understand why I'm getting this error. I'm doing everything in a write transaction right?
activeSchoolClassNotNull { activeSchoolClass ->
    val schoolSubjects = ocjeneSkoleScraper.getSubjects()
    realm.write {
        activeSchoolClass.schoolSubjects = schoolSubjects.toRealmList()
        copyToRealm(activeSchoolClass, updatePolicy = UpdatePolicy.ALL)
        this@SchoolRepositoryImpl.activeSchoolClass = activeSchoolClass
    }
}

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Yes, you are. However, we don't know which line of code is throwing that error so it's possible other code is actually triggering it. e.g. that code works correctly if we make a bunch of assumptions about it. For example .getSubjects may be attempting to modify an object. Best bet is to do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected. Indicate that line, what the expected and actual results were.

The problem was that I needed to get the latest object from realm before modifying it.
realm.write {
    val latestObj = findLatest(obj)
    latestObj.someProperty = "changed"
    copyToRealm(latestObj)
}


Further info may clarify this answer. An objects properties can be directly modified within a write transaction e.g. copyToRealm(latestObj) is not needed as latestObj.someProperty = "changed" updates the property. However, and perhaps this was your point, the object must be live, so the query must occur within the write block, otherwise it's a frozen object and must be converted to a live object to perform the modification. As seen in this example, name is updated.
